# Perl: Include current directory to @INC?

Tags: perl

I'm in the process of moving some websites from an old webserver to a new webserver. The old webserver uses Perl 5.8, the new webserver uses Perl 5.28. One of the differences between the two is that on 5.8, the directory a script is running from is included by default in @INC. Not so with 5.28. This means that cgi scripts that "require" local files are throwing an error.

I know that I can add these lines to a script to solve the problem:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

but the problem with this is, that I need to do this for a **a lot** of scripts.

Is there a way I can add the current directory (.) to @INC for all scripts in one go? Preferably for the www-data user only?

Comment: I wish there was a scripting language that was really good at inserting text into a text file :D  Seriously, though, it's better to add them directly to the files that need it, as much of a chore that it is - you might have thousands of files.  It was removed in 5.26(?) for security reasons.

Comment: You need a small file with configuration settings which you will include in all other files. In feature you will need to make changes in one place and it should take no more than a few minutes.

Comment: I would also advise to add that to scripts. It's won't take _that_ much and if you don't do it now it may never get done, and you'll stay with a hole on your servers. Why not write a script to do it? It'll be fun -- for example, have it scan a file until it runs into non-`use ...` statements (skip comments as well) and then add these two lines. With a bug flashy note perhaps. Can also have it show on screen a few lines around where it would add and await a confirmation, for each file -- so you can take a glance and hit enter for each file...  [reposted to fix a typo that affected meaning]

Comment: `$RealBin` and `.` are not the same thing. `$RealBin` is the script's directory, while `.` is the current work directory. Which one do you want to search?

Comment: I'd also caution that the lines you show _prepend_ `$RealBin` to `@INC` so you'd better not have modules in `$RealBin` with same names as some of `use...` statements later (because the ones from `$RealBin` will get used!), or have this set _after_ all `use...` statements, as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

```
export PERL_USE_UNSAFE_INC=1
```

According to [perldelta](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.26.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Removal-of-the-current-directory-(%22.%22)-from-@INC):

> `PERL_USE_UNSAFE_INC`
>
> There is a new environment variable recognised by the perl interpreter. If this variable has the value 1 when the perl interpreter starts up, then "." will be automatically appended to @INC (except under tainting).
>
> This allows you restore the old perl interpreter behaviour on a case-by-case basis. But note that this is intended to be a temporary crutch, and this feature will likely be removed in some future perl version. It is currently set by the cpan utility and Test::Harness to ease installation of CPAN modules which have not been updated to handle the lack of dot. Once again, don't use this unless you are sure that this will not reintroduce any security concerns.

I would heed the advice and try to discourage setting this, though.  Maybe in a bind, as you're in, it may be okay as you're already at a security risk; but I would definitely make sure to update the files and unset this variable ASAP.

Comment: You can find that in perlrun, but the docs already discourage you from doing it.

Comment: This is unlikely to work. apache sets the PWD to `/`, which is useless to add to `@INC`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no global solution because the path you want to add is different for each script.

One might be tempted to add `.`, but `.` refers to the current directory and not the directory containing the script. It's not correct to do so.

---

You can fix the files using something like the following:

```sh
# See what files will be modified.
find . -name '*.pl'

# Actually modify them.
find . -name '*.pl' -exec perl -pe'$_ .= "use FindBin qw( \$RealBin );\nuse lib \$RealBin;\n" if $. == 1' -i~ {} \;
```

The above makes a backup. Once you're satisfied with the changes, you can remove the backups using

```sh
# See what files will be deleted.
find . -name '*~'

# Actually delete them.
find . -name '*~' -delete
```